# ScrollIntoView to SelectedItem with MVVM (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: xaml, listview, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

In code behind this is done by

```
 ActivityList.ScrollIntoView(ActivityList.SelectedItem);
```

when you come back from the detailpage so that when you return from the detailpage you don't have to start from the top of the ListView.

There are a few examples to scroll to the end of a ListView but not to the SelectedItem.

But how is this done in MVVM? Creating a Behavior with Behavior SDK? And how?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with an attached-property (behavior). This behavior is in a `class` called DataGridExtensions and looks like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollSelectionIntoViewProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "ScrollSelectionIntoView", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(false, ScrollSelectionIntoViewChanged));

private static void ScrollSelectionIntoViewChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = d as DataGrid;
    if (dataGrid == null)
        return;

    if (e.NewValue is bool && (bool)e.NewValue)
        dataGrid.SelectionChanged += DataGridOnSelectionChanged;
    else
        dataGrid.SelectionChanged -= DataGridOnSelectionChanged;
}

private static void DataGridOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems == null || e.AddedItems.Count == 0)
        return;

    DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dataGrid == null)
        return;

    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = UIHelper.FindChildren<ScrollViewer>(dataGrid).FirstOrDefault();
    if (scrollViewer != null)
    {
        dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(e.AddedItems[0]);
    }
}

public static void SetScrollSelectionIntoView(DependencyObject element, bool value)
{
    element.SetValue(ScrollSelectionIntoViewProperty, value);
}

public static bool GetScrollSelectionIntoView(DependencyObject element)
{
    return (bool)element.GetValue(ScrollSelectionIntoViewProperty);
}
```

The code of `UIHelper.FindChildren` is:

```
public static IList<T> FindChildren<T>(DependencyObject element) where T : FrameworkElement
{
    List<T> retval = new List<T>();
    for (int counter = 0; counter < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); counter++)
    {
        FrameworkElement toadd = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, counter) as FrameworkElement;
        if (toadd != null)
        {
            T correctlyTyped = toadd as T;
            if (correctlyTyped != null)
            {
                retval.Add(correctlyTyped);
            }
            else
            {
                retval.AddRange(FindChildren<T>(toadd));
            }
        }
    }
    return retval;
}
```